# Graphcool RELAY Subscription: subscribe to edges

Tags: graphql-js, relayjs, relay, graphcool, relaymodern

```
subscription updateListSubscription {
    User(filter: {mutation_in: [CREATED]}) {
        mutation
        node {
            id
            name
            addressList{
                edges {
                    node {
                        id
                    }
                }
            }                               
        }
    }
}
```

For the above query getting error: Cannot query field 'edges' on type AddressList. Note AddressList is a mapping of each address to each user.

Comment: Ankit, please check your types. Is `AddressList` a connection? Because the error message says it doesn't have edges

Comment: @DenisCappelini AddressList is a connection. If it wasn't, the relay compiler would have given an error. If am i am removing addressList, i am able to get the response in my subscription updater

Comment: I am getting error from web sockets payload with error                             
"Cannot query field 'edges' on type 'Address'. (line 14, column 5):↵    edges {↵    ^"}" @DenisCappelini can you please look into https://gitlab.com/ankit5174/relay-subscription-example this project and let me know where i am going wrong.